# Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader do nothing if no token / wrong token

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

From router:

```
  pipeline :possibly_authorized do
    plug(:fetch_session)

    plug(
      Guardian.Plug.Pipeline,
      module: BoilerplateWeb.Guardian,
      error_handler: BoilerplateWeb.AuthErrorController
    )

    plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, realm: :none
    plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource, allow_blank: true
  end
```

How do I make `plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader` do nothing if token is missing or wrong? Now it raises error via error_handler.

Edit: The goal is to still check for the token, if it's present/valid then next plug (`LoadResource`) would get current_user, if not then current_user should be `nil` without raising.

Comment: VerifyHeader will check the header if it's present. If you don't want it to do anything if it's wrong then just don't include it

Comment: Do you possibly mean how to make it do something else than raising an error? Doing nothing is kind of pointless as was already pointed out. Please try to describe your goal more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/v1.2.1/lib/guardian/plug/verify_header.ex#L94

you can see that guardian will do nothing when token is not found, it only halt when the token is invalid.